# How to unit test javascript function which takes in a parameter using jasmine or mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine, mocha.js

I have a simple question. How do I unit test a function which is dependent on a parameter? Like say for example:

**Code:**

```
function a(param) {
   if(param > 0) 
      return param+value;
   else
      return param;
}
```

How do I unit test function a without having param? I hear this I use mocks or spies in jasmine. Can someone show me an example, I am really confused. Thank you all in advance.

**Edit:**

Thank you for such a conprehensive answer David. I really appreciate it. Here is more information about my question.

This is in fact my true question, I have a file

***snap-fed.js*** :

```
//Code here...
```

Which I would like to unit test comprehensively as you showed me. But I am unsure as to how to do this using jasmine or mocha.

Like how could I test any of the methods of the snap object? How could I unit test snap.eligibility or snap.isSnapResourceEligibile? I have been stuck on this issue for about 2 days, I really don't understand.

They all take in a parameter info which provides info about the object being worked on by the methods.

This was my true question but I did not know how to ask it.

**Edit 2:**

Based on David's template I made this, but it doesn't even run...

***snap-fed.spec.js*** :

```
describe("snap-fed", function() { 

  describe("Properties", function() { 

    it("should exist", function() {
      expect(Allowance).not.toBeUndefined(); 
      expect(AllowanceAdditional).not.toBeUndefined();
      expect(MaxAllowanceHouseholdSize).not.toBeUndefined();
    }); 

    it("should contain correct values", function() {
        expect(Allowance).toEqual([189, 347, 497, 632, 750, 900, 995, 1137]);
        expect(AllowanceAdditional).toBe(142);
        expect(MaxAllowanceHouseholdSize).toBe(Allowance.length);
    }); 
  });

  describe("Functions", functions(){

    it("should return the expected result", function() {
      expect(snap.isSnapResourceEligible(info)).toBeTruthy();
    });

    //Put more test cases for the various methods of snap

  });

});
```

Comment: You provide param in as an argument in the unit test itself, then assert that the return value is as expected.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? What you're saying makes sense, but I think if I saw an example, I would understand much better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test could look like this in Jasmine:

```
    describe("Function a", function() {

      it("is defined", function() {
        expect(a).not.toBeUndefined();
      });

      it("should return expected result for a positive parameter", function() {
        var result = a(19);

        expect(result).toEqual(24);
      });

      it("should return expected result for a negative parameter", function() {
        var result = a(-1);

        expect(result).toEqual(-1);
      });

      it("should return expected result for parameter zero", function() {
        var result = a(0);

        expect(result).toEqual(5);
      });

    });
```

This scenario is expecting the variable `value` inside function `a` to be a constant equal to 5. The scenario can be more complex and the tests would look differently. If there is any logic about the `value` variable, please show it in your question, I will then edit my answer.

**EDIT: test sample for the second part of your question**

So if the eligibility function looked like this after removing the `Q.fcall`:

```
eligibility: function (info) {
            return {
                eligible : snap.isSnapIncomeEligible(info) && snap.isSnapResourceEligible(info),
                savings : snap.calcSavings(info)
            };
    }
```

Then you could test the snap object like this for example:

```
describe("Snap", function() {

  var snap = ... //get the snap object here...

  var disabledMemberInfo = {
    disabledMember: true,
    age: 50,
    fpl: 1.2,
    householdSize: 10,
    moneyBalance: 4000
  };

  it("is defined", function() {
    expect(snap).not.toBeUndefined();
  });

  it("has eligibility defined", function() {
    expect(snap.eligibility).not.toBeUndefined();
  });

  it("return positive eligibility for disabled member with fpl < 1.2 and money balance 4000", function() {

    var result = snap.eligibility(disabledMemberInfo);

    expect(result).not.toBeUndefined();
    expect(result.eligible).not.toBeUndefined();
    expect(result.savings).not.toBeUndefined();

    expect(result.eligible).toEqual(true);
  });

});
```

I didn't cover the whole snap object with tests. But more test will be similar, my code should be an example and more tests built in a similar way.

Comment: Thank you! Your test case makes perfect sense!

Comment: I added the additonal info you requested

Comment: Thank you extending your question, this makes it much more complicated :) I'll be happy to help with it. But please explain me what is the point of the `Q.fcall(function () {...}`. I am not much familiar with Q but this call returns a promise, right? I seems to me like it is totally not needed. I am asking because it is slightly more complex to test async code, so omitting unnecessary promises would make it easier. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, that is a promise. The promises will be omitted from the project, so please ignore that part. And thank you for your willingness to help

Comment: OK! Updated my answer. If you have any questions, let me know please.

Comment: I am trying to run this, but it gives me an error saying **ReferenceError: require is not defined** so it is not recognizing the *require* keyword, how can I make it work?

Comment: I was just trying to show you need to get a reference to the snap object. Please change this line of code to anything which will give you the snap object.

Comment: I got it working, and I couldn't have done any of it without you. Thank you again!